# Long URLs don't stay inside the Bootstrap column

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a WordPress theme with Bootstrap grids, and I see a problem in mobile view. Everything is fixed into the Bootstrap column, but there are some links in the references section that don't stay inside the column and make a mess of my grids and create a horizontal scroll bar:

[image]

[image]

I've tried everything and nothing works, please I need help.

Here is the code from the `single.php`:

```
<div class="c-content-box c-size-md" style="margin-top:4%;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="c-content-blog-post-card-1-grid">
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-8 wow animate fadeInLeft">

                                <div class="c-media 2 img">
                                    <div class="c-overlay-wrapper">
                                        <div class="c-overlay-content">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail( '', array( 'style' => 'max-width:100%; height:auto;' ) ); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php
                                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

                                    ?>

                                    <div class="col-md-12 c-margin-b-60">
                                        <?php
                                            the_post_navigation( array(
                                                'prev_text' => '<button type="button" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6 btn btn-md c-btn-red c-btn-square ">Post Anterior</button>',
                                                'next_text' => '<button type="button" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6 btn btn-md c-btn-red c-btn-square ">Próximo Post</button>',

                                            ));    

                                        ?>
                                    </div>                                         

                                    <?php
                                    echo '<div class="col-md-12 c-margin-t-20">';

                                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                                        comments_template();
                                    endif;

                                endwhile; // End of the loop.
                                    echo '</div>'
                                    ?>

                        </div>



                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                            <div class="col-md-12 wow animate fadeInRight" >
                                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                                    </main><!-- #main -->
                                </div><!-- #primary -->
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add some CSS to `word-wrap` your text.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
.wrapped {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800283/content-posts-doesnt-stay-inside-the-bootstrap-cols</div>

<div class="wrapped">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800283/content-posts-doesnt-stay-inside-the-bootstrap-cols</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.dont-break-out {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please include a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answer(s) provided.